# python 3 C-API extension ImportError

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, dlopen, c-api

I am using Python3 on mac OS X 10.10.2. I am new to python C-API, so I am trying out a simple example of C-API extension from "Python Cookbook" http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch15.html. I think there is some difference between Python2 and Python3. I followed Python3 documentations, but can't find why my case is not working.

Up to building with distills works(`python3 setup.py build` or `python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace`) giving me the `sample.so` file.
I compiled `sample.c` as well getting `sample.o`.

But, when I import from python, I get an error message as shown below, and I don't understand what is going on. Below shows the error message run in ipython3.

Please help me with this issue of extending modules. Thanks!

```
In [1]: import sample
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a769eab12f54> in <module>()
----> 1 import sample

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/suh/pyLNKS/python-api-example/sample/sample.so, 2): Symbol not found: _gcd
Referenced from: /Users/suh/pyLNKS/python-api-example/sample/sample.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/suh/pyLNKS/python-api-example/sample/sample.so

In [2]:
```

Below are the codes for the files `pysample.c`, `sample.c`, `sample.h`, and `setup.py`.

pysample.c

```
1 #include <Python.h>
2 #include "sample.h"
3 
4 
5 static PyObject *py_gcd(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
6     int x, y, result;
7 
8     if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &x, &y)) {
9         return NULL;
10     }
11     result = gcd(x, y);
12     return Py_BuildValue("i", result);
13 }
14 
15 
16 /* module method table */
17 static PyMethodDef SampleMethods[] = {
18     {"gcd", py_gcd, METH_VARARGS, "Greatest commond divisor"},
19    // {"divide", py_divide, METH_VARARGS, "Integer division"},
20     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
21 };
22 
23 static struct PyModuleDef samplemodule = {
24     PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
25     "samle",    /* name of module */
26     "A sample module",  /* doc string, may be NULL */
27     -1, /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, 
28            or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables */
29     SampleMethods   /* methods table */
30 };  
31 
32 PyMODINIT_FUNC
33 PyInit_sample(void){
34     return PyModule_Create(&samplemodule);
35 }   
36
```

sample.c

```
1 /* sample.c */
2 #include <math.h>
3 
4 /* compute the greatest common divisor */
5 int gcd(int x, int y){
6     int g = y;
7     while (x > 0){
8         g = x;
9         x = y % x;
10         y = g;
11     }
12     return g;
13 }
```

sample.h

```
1 /* sample.h */
2 #include <math.h>
3 
4 extern int gcd(int x, int y);
```

setup.py

```
1 # setup.py
2 from distutils.core import setup, Extension
3 
4 module1 = Extension('sample', sources = ['pysample.c'])
5 
6 setup(name='simple',
7         version = '1.0',
8         description = "this is a demo package",
9         ext_modules = [module1]
10         )
11
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a linking problem, where the source code sample.c is not linked so that gcd function is undefined.

Thus, the code setup.py needs to be changed to:

```
1 # setup.py
2 from distutils.core import setup, Extension
3 
4 module1 = Extension('sample', sources = ['pysample.c','source.c'])
5 
6 setup(name='simple',
7         version = '1.0',
8         description = "this is a demo package",
9         ext_modules = [module1]
10         )
11
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the samplemodule structure.
The module name is "sample", not "samle"